# Implement Facebook Login from ZERO

Tags: php, facebook, authentication

Hello and good day to everyone. I am new and I really need help about implementing facebook login on my website.

Let's start with what I understood.

1) I created a login page on my website (login.php), the code is the one found on fb developers page https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.3 (Quickstart section).

2) The login button works, when I click on it a pop up opens asking me to login on facebook and so on.

3) After I login i am redirected to logged.php (I added the redirect function)

4) Now I think I have to take the 1 data (username) used by that user with facebook and store it on my database just to create to him a profile on my website)

I have no idea how to do this last 4 step.

I am just familiar with PHP, (ASP), and easy java / css / mysql, so I am also having problems "writing" the script" but this doesn't matter now.

Can someone please tell me which code should I use on logged.php to take the username of the user (retrieved from facebook) ?

I just need to save it in a variable and then will handle with php, but the key point (my doubt) is how to take it from the facebook pop-up..

I hope I explained well my problem, I think is easy but I am not much familiar with any API (I just implemented API of youtube and the result is not that great) So any help may be appreciated.

Thanks again.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn’t a website to get experienced developers to write code for you for free. Try yourself, and if you encounter a _specific_ issue, then please post a question. Also take the [Stack Overflow tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) in the meantime to learn what questions are acceptable on the site.

Comment: HI, you can get all  public data from FB, Please use https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user